# Select the first condition per group iteration

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
          A           B   C   D
0  01:00:00  2002-01-16  10   3
1  01:30:00  2002-01-16  10 -12
2  02:00:00  2002-01-16  10   7
3  01:00:00  2002-01-17  20  33
4  01:30:00  2002-01-17  20 -27
5  02:00:00  2002-01-17  20  12

results = {}
```

I want to select one row per each `A` group, taking the **first** row which satisfy one of the next conditions:

- D >= C*(0.5)
- D <= C*(-1)
- Else, take last row.

Output should be:

```
          A           B   C   D
1  01:30:00  2002-01-16  10 -12
3  01:00:00  2002-01-17  20  33
```

I´ve tried:

```
grouped = df.groupby('B')

for name, group in grouped:
    if (group["D"] >= group["C"]*(0.5)).any():
        results[name] = group[group["D"] >= group["C"]*(0.5)].head(1)
    elif (group["D"] <= group["C"]*(-1)).any():
        results[name] = group[group["D"] <= group["C"]*(-1)].head(1)
    else:
        results[name] = group.tail(1)
```

Comment: What's wrong with example that you provided?

Comment: Doesn´t select the first row which satisfy one of the next conditions

Comment: Are you grouping by `A` as you say, or `B` which it looks like in your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less what you have but using `groupby.apply`, also from your desired output it doesn't seem you prioritize the first condition, in which case, you need to combine the two conditions with *or* `|`:

```
def first_last(g):
    # this is used at multiple places, cache the condition
    cond = g.D.ge(g.C.mul(0.5)) | g.D.le(g.C.mul(-1))

    if cond.any():
        return g[cond].iloc[0]
    else:
        return g.iloc[-1]

df.groupby('B', as_index=False).apply(first_last)

#          A             B   C    D
#0  01:30:00    2002-01-16  10  -12
#1  01:00:00    2002-01-17  20   33
```

Or a shorter version:

```
def first_last(g):
    cond = g.D.ge(g.C.mul(0.5)) | g.D.le(g.C.mul(-1))

    return g[cond].iloc[0] if cond.any() else g.iloc[-1]

df.groupby('B', as_index=False).apply(first_last)
```